# computer basics problem

Tags: ascii

hi everybody can  anyone tell me answer of this question ?
 i created a simple txt file. it contain only two words and the words are hello word according to i studied computer uses ascii code to store the text on disk or memory .In ascii code each letter or symbol is represented by one byte or in simple words one byte is used to store a symbol.
Now the problem is this when ever i saw the size of file it shows 11 byte I understand 9 byte for words one byte for space makes the total of 10 then why it is showing 11 byte size .i tried different things such as changing the name of file saving it with shortest name possible or longest name possible but it did not change the total storage 
so can any body explain why it is happening? i tried this thing over window or Linux(Ubuntu.centos) system result is same.

Comment: Don't want to be patronizing, but are you sure it says "hello word" and not "hello world" ?

Answer (score 3):

```
pax> echo hello word >outfile.txt

pax> ls -al outfile.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax   pax   11 2010-11-19 15:34 outfile.txt

pax> od -xcb outfile.txt 
0000000    6568    6c6c    206f    6f77    6472    000a
          h   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   d  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 040 167 157 162 144 012

pax> hd outfile.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 64 0a                 |hello word.|
0000000b
```

As per above, you're storing `"hello word"` *and* the newline character. That's 11 characters in total. If you *don't* want the newline, you can use something like the `-n` option of `echo` (which doesn't add the newline):

```
pax> echo -n hello word >outfile.txt

pax> ls -al outfile.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax   pax   10 2010-11-19 15:36 outfile.txt

pax> od -xcb outfile.txt 
0000000    6568    6c6c    206f    6f77    6472
          h   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   d
        150 145 154 154 157 040 167 157 162 144

pax> hd outfile.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 64                    |hello word|
0000000a
```

Comment: @paxdiablo This is a good command to know!  Also I saw that someone said file/strings on a disc are not null terminated (which would take up an extra byte)?  Is this true?

Comment: `hd` also produces clear output by default (hexadecimal and then the readable characters).

Comment: @typoknig, well, they're null terminated if you write the NUL character out :-) But that's pretty unusual.

Comment: @Matthew, that's a _much_ better command. I may never use `od` again (except makbe on the older UNIXes we have to support). Added the output of that to make it clearer, cheers.

Comment: @typo, @pax is right.  NUL terminators aren't added automatically by text editing problems, but you could of course do so manually.  There is no need, though, since the OS knows the length of the file.  In fact, programs (e.g. [`hg diff`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles), among others) often use this as the definition of "binary".  "Binary" files have NUL, "text" files don't; however, certain text encodings (e.g. UTF-16) do have *embedded* NULs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the content of the file you can perform an octal dump of it using the "od" command under linux "od ". Most probably what you will see is a CR (carriage return) and a LN (linefeed). 
The name of the file has nothing to do with his size.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Did you a new line in the text file (`\n`)? Just because this character cannot be seen does not mean it is not there.